# How to use Python3.5 typing as runtime checks?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I use Python3.5 typing module in order to provide the type hints to my classes and functions. It works well with PyCharm as it exploits these hints.

However, I would like to force the python interpreter to perform the runtime type checks when type the hints are provided (or at least throw some warnings).

**Current state:**

```
In [1]: def times2(number: int):
   ...:     return number + number
   ...: 

In [2]: times2(8)
Out[2]: 16

In [3]: times2('8')
Out[3]: '88'
```

**Desired state:**

```
In [1]: def times2(number: int):
   ...:     return number + number
   ...: 

In [2]: times2(8)
Out[2]: 16

In [3]: times2('8')
Out[3]: Assertion error: '8' is not an int
```

Can I somehow enforce python to do that?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: Maybe compile-time type checking would fit your needs? [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an assertion like so:

```
def times2(number: int):
    assert type(number) is IntType, "number is not an int: %r" % number
    return number + number
```

Or have I misinterpreted your question?

Comment: I can explain the concept of assertions, how and where to use them if you like?

Comment: well this is desired behavior, however I thought it would result in it somehow automatically just by writing the type-hint above. Nevermind, thanks

Comment: @petrbel oh right, no you would need to use an assertion or perhaps throw an exception

Comment: sure, but my point was not doing that explicitely but let the python do it itself by providing just the type hint. Anyway `mypy` seems pretty usable so I'll try that :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals

> While the proposed typing module will contain some building blocks for runtime type checking […] third party packages would have to be developed to implement specific runtime type checking functionality

and

> It should also be emphasized that Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention.

Python typing is designed as a sort of lint tool, so that a developer can check whether their code is calling other code correctly (as far as typing supports — types are checked but you can still have invalid values!).  It is not meant for runtime checks, and not meant to validate or reject user input.  Other libraries can build on the typing concepts to implement these, in the stdlib (https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) or third-party (https://github.com/search?q=python+runtime+typing&type=Repositories).